# Two suggestion popups from linting

Tags: atom-editor, elm, lint, nuclide-editor

I just started using Atom because of its Elm integration, and now I have a little problem with datatips. It shows two popups and I would like to disable the lower one.

Which is why I'm asking if there is a solution to solve the problem besides uninstalling nuclide (the upper one) and I am pretty sure there is one or even multiple.

[image]

Comment: What Elm plugins have you installed? Can you disable them one by one to see which one is the one you'd like to remove?